# infinite loops in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having issues with a script that functions similarly to this. Sometimes the script just completely gets stuck in the loop and I'm unsure why. It seems to happen when I have two such loops running simultaneously.

```
async function monitorResouce(){

    while(true){
        console.log("before async");
        await doHttpRequest();
        console.log("after sync");

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setImmediate(resolve));
    }
}

monitorResouce();
monitorResouce();
```

Is there something inherently problematic about writing code like this? If so, what is the preferred way to continually call an async function?

Comment: This statement  `while(true)` , when are you going to break it ?

Comment: Most of my use cases need to run forever. For example, I'm monitoring the performance of my website and logging the results.

Comment: When you say stuck, you mean your `doHttpRequest()` is not resolved? or, like @PrabodhM says, it's because of the `while(true)` loop?

Comment: I mean that it will print "after async" and never make it to the top of the loop to print "before async" again. If there's no issue with the concept of the code, I'm just gonna assume it's a bug in V8 and/or a memory leak.

Comment: `doHttpRequest()` is the only thing that **may** prevent this code to be a synchronous, blocking, infinite loop. With a really strong emphasys on the word *may* and not *does*. The way Promises and `setImmediate` work in JS this may never stop executing JS and letting the browser do something else. Like rendering the window or so. You should really interrupt the JS execution once in a while, by using stuff like `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: I'm running in node, but I get the point. It seems like more of a deadlock than infinite loop because there are no console messages. I was actually using setTimeout(resolve,0) in place of the setImmediate for awhile and the freezing problem appeared even more frequently.

Comment: Does `doHttpRequest()` return a promise?  Is that promise resolved?  Where's your error handling if the http request fails?  What exact logging do you see?